# Old extensions still loading after upgrade to php 7.0?

Tags: php, ubuntu, server

i upgraded from php 5.0 to php7.0 using onderj's PPA
(on live server)

Everything went well, but it seems that old extensions are still loaded??
php-v gives these things:

```
        PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/interbase.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/interbase.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
        PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/ldap.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/ldap.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
        PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/odbc.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/odbc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
        PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_dblib.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_dblib.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
        PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_firebird.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_firebird.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
        PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_odbc.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_odbc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
        PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_pgsql.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_pgsql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
        PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_sqlite.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_sqlite.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
        PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/pgsql.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/pgsql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
        PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/pspell.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/pspell.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
        PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/recode.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/recode.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
        PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/sqlite3.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/sqlite3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
        PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/tidy.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/tidy.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

Any one any clue how to fix?? (without breaking server)

Comment: No, the warnings mean that it **cannot** load the library (because it does not exist at said path).

Comment: for example, pdo_firebird is in the list...

phpinfo() says:
              adittional ini files parsed: /etc/php/7.0/cgi/conf.d/20-pdo_firebird.ini

Comment: inetrbase is loaded here:  /etc/php/7.0/cgi/conf.d/20-interbase.ini

Comment: It isn't loaded, it tries to but it can't since the .so file doesn't exist. Maybe it is located at a different path, look for it and if it is at a different path, update the .ini file.

Comment: it is allready loaded if you look at phpinfo() , so i think it are the old extensions from php5 that still are trying to load

Comment: seems they were not installed, even if phpinfo says the ini files were loaded

Comment: You do know that the W in wamp stands for Windows.... I guess not